# Rails Active Job output to custom log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have several jobs added to Rails Active Job, but is there any way, we can have separate custom log file for output for each Rails Active Job?

ActiveJob1 -> activejob1.log

ActiveJob2 -> activejob2.log

Comment: Why would you like to have it this way?

Comment: Because we are running large number of jobs with extensive output simultenously and want to have the ability to track the execution for each of them separately through the log if required